# Why am I getting a fatal error when trying to get the diff() of 2 DateTime Objects

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to find the difference in days between 2 timestamps (using `DateTime`). The first is the Current Date. The second is a pre-determined date stored in an SQL DB

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$dt = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM medications WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    while($med = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $medname = $med['medication'];
        $refill = $med['refilldate'];
        $refillby = (new DateTime($refill))->format('Y-m-d');
        $interval = $dt->diff($refillby); //Error Below Received on this Line
        echo $diff;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I received:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in...

Everything I've found online is when there is a conflict between Date and DateTime, but I am not using Date. Also, if I `echo` my `$refillby` variable, it is in the correct and same format as `$dt`

Comment: DateTime::format() returns a string. DateTime::diff() Requires a DateTime. Using a string instead of a DateTime isn't going to work...

Comment: Just a general rule in the future, `var_dump($dt);` could have saved you a lot of time in figuring out what was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments state, you can't format the DateTime... try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$dt = new DateTime();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM medications WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    while($med = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $medname = $med['medication'];
        $refill = $med['refilldate'];
        $refillby = new DateTime($refill);
        $interval = $dt->diff($refillby);
        echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); //you need to make sure this var matches - it doesn't above.
    }
}
```